# HTML Form returns nothing to clipboard when copying text field value using Selenium Python?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, clipboard, forms

I'm doing a particular automation task using python selenium (currently using mac system)- and for some reason my `webElement.text` returns nothing for a text field i'd like to copy. Hence I'm trying to copy paste the values, but for whatever reason, the `.send_keys` works (as I'm able to see values being entered, the cursor moving etc, but after the command+c step, I dont have the values in my clipboard. I tried pasting the clipboard contents via xerox module and it retrieves only the stuff I'd previously copied manually- my selenium driven clipboard content is not seen. I'm wondering how to get around this issue?

/code

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import xerox

elem = browser.find_elements_by_name("callback_url_0")[0]
#elem.send_keys("bar") # for testing purposes, and it works

elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a') #highlight all in box
elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c') #copy
#elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'v') #
#xerox.copy()
xerox.paste() #this pastes my old system junk, nothing from the webdriver session
```

I've even tried `Key.COMMAND` as I'm on a mac, but nothing changed. Any way to get around or even hack around this issue?

UPDATE:
So, the issue is that I'm working with a text field where in, I'm able to `send_keys` and type text, but am not able to get its content, both by `webDriver Element.text` as well as copy paste using above described method. My goal is to get its content and process it further in my script. What could be the issue here and what can I really try to get around this?

UPDATE:
Using command chaining (answer below) perform copy and paste. But my clipboard has no content i.e., returns blank value. The same as the .text method. What could be the issue? Something with the form?

Here's my form html:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12">
<input app-vast-url-validate="" type="url" class="input-full-width ng-valid-required ng-valid-vast-url ng-dirty ng-touched ng-valid ng-valid-url" id="callback_url_0" name="callback_url_0" ng-model="callback.url" placeholder="Enter Callback URL" ng-keyup="onAddCallbackFormControl($event, callback)" required="" style="">
</div>
</div>
```

UPDATE:
So I am instead choosing to right click and copy through the context menu as none of the methods seem to be working. However even with the context menu I’m unable to hit copy either through Keys.DOWN_ARRAY or send_keys(‘c’,’c’). I really need to pick up that data- any suggestions welcome- either hacks and workarounds or understanding what’s really going on here?

Comment: try using actions class for this scenario

Comment: Could you please illustrate a simple example?

Answer (score 0):

You could try actions for this :

**key_down**(value, element=None)
Sends a key press only, without releasing it.
Should only be used with modifier keys (Control, Alt and Shift).

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('c').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

**key_up**(value, element=None)
Releases a modifier key.

```
ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('c').key_up(Keys.CONTROL).perform()
```

For more reference you can follow this link :

[WebDriver API](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains)

**Update** :

Here is my HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>
Stack over flow
</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this page there are **two input** box I'm sending some keys to **first check** box and then I'm doing `CTRL+A` followed by `CTRL+C`.

Then Clicking on **second input** box and pasting the **same** value.

Here is the code :

```
driver.find_element_by_name('fname').send_keys("Deepak")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.key_down(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).send_keys('a').keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform()
        actions.keyDown(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).sendKeys("c").keyUp(Keys.LEFT_CONTROL).build().perform()
time.sleep(2)
element =  driver.find_element_by_name('lname')
element.click()
element.send_Keys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "v"), "");
```

Comment: This is able to perform copy and paste. But my clipboard has no content i.e., returns blank value. The same as the .text method. What could be the issue?

Comment: after copy the value just try to print it on console.

Comment: How? I’ve tried to command+v as well as with xerox— both return empty strings

Comment: when you are trying to get value , after send keys and click on a submit button or before that ?

Comment: There’s no submit- the text field has data already which I need to fetch. Also strictly I don’t even know if this is a proper HTML form- the website I’m trying to scrape from isn’t exactly world class- so I’m not sure what to try

Comment: @Deepak : Check my updated answer. It may resolve your issue.

Comment: No it did not. I trying to get around by using shift and key chaining 300 left arrows. That seems to work, I’m able to select- but not yet able to copy and paste.  I guess for whatever reason my Keys. COMMAND isn’t working. Need a work around that.

Comment: Please remove your answer. Neither your comments nor your answer is really helpful to anyone.

Comment: @Deepak : How did you jump on that conclusion ? This answer provided by me is accurate and I'm confident about this. Very disappointing that you used  my logic which is "key_down left shift and pressing right_arrow like 300 times " . Although I will not remove my answer , because it would be beneficial for future readers. If you can't appreciate the effort of a user who tries their best to provide you solution and instead you criticize ,   then SO isn't right place for you !

Comment: @Deepak : The person who downvoted my answer yesterday , he/she had taken his/her action back. Because the person who downvoted it , did not have strong points to criticize my answer ! However I am going to flag your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Safari I've raised this with apple back in March.

https://bugreport.apple.com/web/?problemID=38222248 (though you'll not be able to see this bug as they are not shown to other users).

I was using:
**mac OS:** High Sierra 10.13.3
**Safari Technology Preview:** Release 50 (Safari 11.2, WebKit 13606.1.5)
**Selenium-java:** 3.7.1
**JDK:** 1.8.0_161

I tried lots of alternatives to get the copy event (`COMMAND+C`) to trigger, without success, including:
`input.sendKeys(Keys.COMMAND, "c")`;
Using `Keys.CONTROL`, `Keys.META` and the `ctrl+insert` rather than **COMMAND**.

I got acknowledgment by email that my bug report had been looked at but nothing since then.

I didn't find a workaround other than extracting the text from the multiple webelements individually and combining it to create the entire string as if it had been copied with a ctrl+a and ctrl+c.

I'll update this issue if I ever hear back from apple.

This was my demo code from the bug. Before running the script, pre populate the OS clipboard with some known text (just highlight and copy some text by hand)

```
package com.sas.aft.overview;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariOptions;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException    {

    SafariOptions options = new SafariOptions();
    options.setUseTechnologyPreview(true);
    WebDriver webDriver = new SafariDriver(options);

    webDriver.navigate().to("https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_textarea");
    webDriver.switchTo().frame("iframeResult");

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    WebElement input = webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea")); 
    input.click();

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    new Actions(webDriver).keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).sendKeys("a").keyUp(Keys.COMMAND).perform();

    Thread.sleep(1000);
    new Actions(webDriver).keyDown(Keys.COMMAND).sendKeys("c").keyUp(Keys.COMMAND).perform();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    Transferable contents = clipboard.getContents(null);
    try {
        System.out.print("Clipboard: " + (String)contents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor) + "\n"); 
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) { 
        //ignore
    }

    webDriver.quit();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE ON SAFARI BUG**
The bug I raised:
38222248 Command key does not work with copy for safaridriver with selenium automation

Was updated by Apple on 2nd July '18 with this comment:
A solution is under investigation. We will follow up with you again when it is available.


Was updated by Apple on 17th July '18 with this comment:
We believe this issue has been resolved in the latest macOS 10.14 beta

Answer (score -1):

Although this probably isn’t the elegant or right way to go about things but I managed to get the job done ie copy paste using browser automation. So the HTML input field returned null, so I resorted to copy paste. Command + A wasn’t working so resorted to manually selecting key_down left shift and pressing right_arrow like 300 times to select my full text using Action chaining. Command + C wasn’t working then, so I tried the context_menu which again worked but I couldn’t select copy option from the menu both by send_keys(‘c’) twice or by arrow_down six times. Instead I found a helpful trick on Mac (not sure about Linux or win) that let’s you copy with control and insert. Did that worked like a charm. My xerox.paste() has the content from the page as copied by selenium and I can proceed now to process that Data. Thank you all

Comment: Please post example code and list your versions (mac OS, selenium, browser). For `Command + A` did you try example above?
Is your right click context menu specific to your application rather than the native browser menu - as AFAIK selenium can't interact with the native one, and for the versions I'm using there is another bug I've logged with apple where the appearance of the Safari context menu actually blocks all other webdriver interactions - normally you can close it with an `ESC` key (For what it is worth, my bug 38504318 which has been updated to indicate it's a duplicate of 37732986).